# Displaying post/page info on a homepage using get_post()

Tags: get-post

I've been asked to make some changes to a Wordpress site and the previous dev has displayed information from certain current pages on the homepage.

What's confusing me is how they've managed to do this... he/she seems to have categorised certain pages by number. For example, the following WP_Query() code seems to target a set number of pages:

```
        <?php $id = get_post(41);
        setup_postdata($id); ?>

        <?php

        $args = array(

            'post_parent' => $id,
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'ASC'

        );

        $child_query = new WP_Query($args);

        ?>
```

There are other WP_Query()'s throughout the page that target other posts and the only difference is the number in `get_post()` but I can't work out how they've done this...

Anyone done/come across this before?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You don't want to hardcode post IDs like that

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out, when in the admin area of a page/post you can find the post ID in the browser URL:

```
http://localhost/newsite/wp-admin/post.php?post=1807&action=edit
```

So the previous dev simply uses this page as a 'parent', and refers to it as they set `$id = get_post(1807);`

Now the query find posts/pages that a 'children' of this page.

Answer (score 0):

41 is the post ID. The developer has hardcoded the specific page that he wants to get the data from. get_post(41) will grab the associated details of the page with that ID. You can use a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpsite-show-ids/ to see the id of your page directly in the admin dashboard to determine which page is being used here.